# What does Taylor Mason mean by predicting delta of a stock?

Tags: plot-explanation, billions

> A stock is like a living organism. A sparrow, say. And we are able to create an emergent-based abstraction of that sparrow, which closely approximates the sparrow itself, accounting for migration patterns, wind, weather, and other variables. We can create a similar abstraction of a stock combining the information from the specific ETFs, which represent its underlying dependencies. And if we apply this to the stock we can predict its delta, following the path of its extracted self, because nature follows abstraction.

- Taylor Mason, Billions S02E10

I tried asking on [quant se](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36295/can-we-predict-the-delta-of-a-stock-the-delta-of-a-stock-is-pm-1-right) but no luck. I'm basically wondering if we can always predict a stock's delta. I have a feeling the show might've been just saying a bunch of words to sound smart but then turned out incorrect. The thing is the stock's delta should be either +1 or -1 depending on what position you are, namely, resp, long or short.

Related: [Was Rachel Zane talking about a poison pill?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/72297/was-rachel-zane-talking-about-a-poison-pill)

Comment: Delta means which way it will go if I recall correctly.

Comment: How are the linked questions related?

Comment: @Joachim good question. it's another finance(/economics/financial economics) question. just wondering if perhaps it's the case that either both are on-topic or both are off-topic....also others might be interested. lol.

Comment: @Paulie_D you might be thinking of 'change'. however, delta is 'rate of change' relative (since rate of change is always relative) to a stock. so a stock's rate of change against itself is just 1. anything's rate of change against itself is 1. of course if you're short instead of long what you have is negative of a stock instead of a stock so the rate of change of -BCLC relative to BCLC is just -1

Answer (score 4):

**Delta** is **how much the price of a derivative (such as a stock option) is expected to move relative to a small move in the price of the underlying instrument (such as a stock)**. It is quoted as a number between -1 and +1.

For example, say a stock is currently priced at 200 pence and the option to buy it in 10 days' time (a "call" option) at the same price is at 15 pence. If a rise in the stock's price to 210 pence would cause the option price to rise to 24 pence (the option now being "in the money"), the delta is (24-15)/(210-200) = +0.9. If on the other hand, we consider an option to sell it at 200 pence in 10 days' time (a "put" option, which would then be "out of the money"), and if the price of that option might be expected to fall from 15 pence to 6 pence, then its delta would be (6-15)/(210-200) = -0.9.

In the world of financial derivatives, delta is called a "Greek". You can read about delta and other kinds of financial "Greek" (not all of which are named after letters of the Greek alphabet) here: [Greeks (finance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)).

(Note that is not true that delta can only be +1 or -1).

What Taylor Mason (or their ghostwriter if they used one) probably meant was that **taking into account the prices of various derivatives**, including some which may be far more "exotic" than simple call and put options, and which have various different expiration dates, **you can get the "market view" of the expected graph of the stock price in the time to come**, "delta" meaning "change".

Note that when the answerer on quant.se told you that the delta of a stock is always 1, what that meant is that if you take the stock price as its own derivative, then of course its expected change per its expected change is always 1. This information is presumably not what you were asking for, though.

Comment: thanks. '(Note that is not true that delta can only be +1 or -1).' --> but of a stock it is true right? that's precisely what i'm wondering.

Comment: wait what you're describing about the delta of the 0.9 and -0.9 is for an OPTION and not for a STOCK right?

Comment: 'take the stock price as its own derivative' --> so what's the meaning here? taylor refers to delta of some derivative on a stock rather than the stock itself?

Comment: @BCLC - "Delta", when it doesn't just mean "change", has the specific meaning of the change in the price of something (a derivative) divided by the change in the stock price. The answerer on quant.se was being a bit "clever" by "interpreting" the phrase "delta of a stock" to imply that the "something" is the stock price itself. Nobody would really use the phrase that way, because d/dx of x is always 1. See my 5th para for what I think Taylor Mason or his ghostwriter meant.

Comment: Note that the expected movement in the stock price derived from the knowledge about the prices of derivatives is likely to be more detailed than simply "it is expected to rise by x pence by the stated date". It may for example by expressed in a curve stretching from now until that date that is quite complicated in shape, and not only that but one might also be able to derive the "market expectation" of the changing probability throughout that period that the stock price will actually be close (or very close, etc.) to its expected level.

Comment: @galacticninja a character in a tv series doesn't use a ghostwriter. The person who answered presumably had no idea who Taylor Mason was, and answered as though they were a real person. This presumed intent does not need to be preserved.

Comment: @KateGregory IMO, that part of your edit should instead be a comment directed to the answerer. Since I'm not sure what their intent is, I'm leaning toward keeping the answerer's original wording rather than changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary to ool:

> Upper-case delta (Δ) often means "change" or "the change in" in mathematics. For example, if the variable "x" stands for the movement of an object, then "Δx" means "the change in movement." Scientists use this mathematical meaning of delta often in physics, chemistry, and engineering, and it appears often in word problems.

https://sciencing.com/delta-math-6678201.html

Amount of "change" (difference) is the informal, general meaning in mathematics across many fields.

Comment: thanks. ah you mean the use here is more like the informal usage of the term delta meaning change rather than the specific (mathematical) finance term (despite that the show is about finance) ?

Comment: Yeah.  It's also a Hollywood signal that they are geeks—geeks talk about "deltas" :)

Comment: oh LOL ok i get it now. thanks. shame ring bell x3 to them!